# Move changes to a different commit when interactive rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

While cleaning up (i.e. mostly squashing) the history of some bigger feature, I often end up with the following situation:

```
Commit A:
  - change A.1
  - change A.2
  - change A.3

// EDIT: maybe some more commits

Commit B:
  - change B.1
  - change B.2
  - change B.3
```

Suppose that now I want to move `change B.1` to commit A using an interactive rebase. The only way I have found so far to do this, is:

1. Start `rebase -i`
2. Edit commit B
3. Split commit B in tmp commit and commit B (`reset HEAD^` and then `add -p`)
4. Start `rebase -i`
5. Fixup tmp commit in commit A

This requires two rebases and is pretty cumbersome. Also I have to rewrite the commit message of commit B when splitting.

Is there any better/more efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a significant improvement, but

1. `git rebase -i A^`
2. `git cherry-pick --no-commit B`
3. `git add -p`
4. `git commit --amend`
5. `git reset --hard`
6. `git rebase --continue`

would be another option.

Comment: Am I getting this right that this will merge double changes when applying `B`, so depending on the complexity of the history (other commits between `A` and `B` for example), applying `B` may create an unnecessary merge conflict?

Comment: Oh, it wasn't obvious that there might be intervening commits. If you have commits between A and B that touch the same code you'll have to resolve the conflicts no matter what method you use to copy or move the patch hunk to A. But you're probably right that what I proposed can result in another conflict when rebase attempts to apply commit B.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm interested in your use of `git reset --hard` to clear the unstaged changes - does it have any advantages over `git checkout .`?

Comment: Some more notes: (1) this will only work to move a change back to an earlier commit - if you need to move a change forward to a later commit, you will have to use the method outlined in the question. (2) you need a `git reset` after the cherry pick as those changes will already be staged. (3) when it gets round to applying commit B you shouldn't get any conflicts, it should just skip any changes that have already been applied (assuming the changes you moved to A were cleanly separated from the changes left in B).